# How to set tcp_syncookies by golang

Tags: go, tcp

Can tcp_syncookies be set by golang? I know that i can write /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies, but this will affect all the process. Is there some way to set it only affect my own process (write by golang)